# Azure Pipeline Build Issue

Tags: azure, pipeline

[image]

I am getting this error in a build which was working in my devops pipeline.... does anyone know how to fix this please?

Comment: looks like a unit test failure to me on first glance. Have you tried running the unit test locally and see if everything passes?

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems like you have the wrong .NET Version for the Runtime.
Try to use this step before:

```
- task: UseDotNet@2
      inputs:
        version: '3.x'
        includePreviewVersions: true
```